# How to .setColor() as a PGM value

Tags: java, colors, pgm

How can I take the values from a PGM file, set the value as the color, then use that color to `fillRect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the easiest is to transform the PGM color to a Java Color is using HSB to express the PGM grayscale.

```
new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(0, 0, (float)actualValue/maximumValueFromPGMHeader))
```